# How To Input Data From CSV Into A Browser Using UI Path?

Tags: csv, rpa, uipath

I am new to UI Path and would like to use a CSV file that holds data into a web browser to fill out an online form. So far I have done the following:

Open Browser (adding the url)
Type Into (to type in username)
Type Into (to type in a password)
Click (to log-in)
Read CSV
For Each Row

And that is as far as I can get. There is box that states "Enter a VB Expression" and no matter what I put into here, I get a validation error saying that the expression is not declared.

Can anyone explain how this works and what I should be typing in here and why?

Comment: Please watch all tutorials from UiPath Acedemy. They will show you anything you need. After that come back and ask advanced things. This is something really basic. And you will get some more issues like this because those things are all shown in the tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Enter a VB expression should be "A variable with a type that's a collection type or Object".
For example in this case, it is DataTable type as picture below.
Code project: [Robotic-Process-Automation-UiPath-Test-ReadCSV00001](https://github.com/akkapolk/Robotic-Process-Automation-UiPath-Test-ReadCSV00001)
[image: Robotic-Process-Automation-UiPath-Test-ReadCSV00001]

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-each-next-statement)

Comment: Thank you for your help